# Count even numbers in scheme

Tags: scheme

[image: I get this error message]

I have my checked even numbers and now I don't know how to count those evens by calling the count_even function. Could someone help me to figure this out?

```
 (define (count_even l)
   (length (filter even? l)))

 (define (check_even lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
       ((not (pair? lst))
          (if (even? lst) (list lst) '()))
          (else
             (append (check_even (car lst))
             (check_even (cdr lst))))))
 (count_even lst)
```

Comment: The error comes from the last line, where you execute your function: `(count_even lst)` because `lst` is not a variable at that point. You need to pass an actual value like this: `(count_even (list 1 2 3 4 5))`

Comment: Note that, as your `check_even` function returns a list with just the even, you should be using `check_even` instead of `filter` (your function already does the filtering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd like to call your `check_even` function like this:

```
 (define (count_even l)
    (length (filter_even l)))
```

But, I recommend you change the name to `filter_even`, because what your function is doing is filtering, not checking (checking is what `even?` does).

Also, in `check_even` you do some extra calculations that are not necessary, like the `append` (unless you expect nested lists), the extra `if` (you already have a `cond` there so no need of `if`), and invoking the `check_even` function again when you already know there is just one element left:

```
 (define (check_even lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          ((even? (car lst)) (cons (car lst) (check_even (cdr lst))))
          (else (check_even (cdr lst)))))
```

To test use:

```
(check_even (list 1 2 3 4 5))
```

Comment: have you tried the OP's `check_even` with `'((2) (3) ((4)))`? Is `append` really serving no purpose there? What would *your* function return? Would it ever return anything `(filter even? ...)` wouldn't?